# Installation on local wordpress server

Tags: wordpress, installation, failure

I'm trying to run CiviCRM v.5.34.0 with Wordpress v.5.6.1 on a local server. Unfortunately the installation of CiviCRM crashes with the following error:

`` Fatal error: Uncaught Civi\Setup\Exception\SqlException: Cannot execute CREATE TABLE `civicrm_address_format` ( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Address Format Id', `format` text [...] ``

[image]

The server is running via xampp v3.2.4:

- Server-Typ: MariaDB
- Server-Verbindung: SSL wird nicht verwendet Dokumentation
- Server-Version: 10.4.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.2
- Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.2
- PHP-Erweiterung: mysqli Dokumentation curl Dokumentation mbstring Dokumentation
- PHP-Version: 8.0.2

The mysql user has all privileges and GRANT access.

I really would like to test CiviCRM to see if it satisfies my needs, which it promises to do.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Even though it looks like a SQL error, it might be a php 8 issue. CiviCRM hasn't been well tested with php 8.

Comment: Thank you. Although not fixing the problem with the original setup, I was able to set up a running CiviCRM on an xampp version with php 7.3.27. If you can add this as an answer I will mark it accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Have added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an incompatibilty with php 8, even though the message initially suggests a SQL problem.