# Installation fault on Wordpress hosted site

Tags: wordpress, installation, failure

Tried installing on a WP server.
Versions: WordPress version 6.0.3
Active theme: Twenty Twenty-One (version 1.6)
Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 4.6)
PHP version 7.4.32
Zend Engine v3.4.0,
Zend OPcache v7.4.32
(what's a Zend..?)

Installation location is /home//crm/wp-content/plugins; I don't have root access: this is a shared server, but I do have proper bash access as a user via cPanel terminal.
Installation crashes at the point I go to wp-admin settings and click on "civiCRM installer".

The diagnostics are
"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."
and
An error of type E_PARSE was caused in line 1 of the file /home//crm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code. Error message: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '('

Bug?

This looks similar to [Installation on local wordpress server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38889/installation-on-local-wordpress-server) but using much more recent versions.

In that trouble ticket the user did some digging into what the database itself was doing. I don't have that knowledge.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're really installing CiviCRM 4.6? That's quite a few years old now. Perhaps try with the version from https://civicrm.org/download

Comment: Also that `//` in `/home//crm` looks a little odd.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old version of CiviCRM that is probably not be compatible with PHP 7.4 or WordPress 6. CiviCRM 4.6 [was released in 2015](https://civicrm.org/blog/kurund/announcing-civicrm-46-release) so is very old and no longer supported.

As Christian suggests, I'd recommend that you install the latest version of CiviCRM (currently 5.54) from: https://civicrm.org/download